# Large data analysis - learning resources

Tags: references, large-data

My question is very simple: which learning resources (books, courses, online courses, and so on) about "large data analysis" would you suggest to a graduate with a strong background in Machine Learning and Computer Science?

**Edit:** I am looking for something similar to section 17 of this very well known online course: https://www.coursera.org/course/ml (you can click on preview lectures to check it out) but in very much detail and many other different methods/algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New York University has a course on Large Scale data analysis that covers most of the topics (and many more) I was looking for. It is very complete and all the materials are available (videos and slides):

http://cilvr.cs.nyu.edu/doku.php?id=courses:bigdata:slides:start

Additionally, further information about Stochastic Methods is available in this presentation:

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/events/mls2013/downloads/stochastic_gradient.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The Udacity course [Introduction to Hadoop and MapReduce](https://www.udacity.com/course/ud617) might be a good place to start.

**Addition in response to question edit:** Maybe the textbook [Mining of Massive Datasets](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds.html) would be useful.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I already knew about that course, but it is too specific in my opinion. I am looking for something that extends section 17 of this very well known online course: https://www.coursera.org/course/ml (you can click on preview lectures to check it out).

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of these YouTube videos by Nando de Freitas:

http://www.youtube.com/user/ProfNandoDF/videos

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, I didn't see any video about the specific topic of large data analysis.